# How to add plain text files into a jar using sbt built

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

I have a project with layout

```
MyProject
   -- src
   -- target
   -- myfiles
        -- myfile1.txt
        -- myfile2.txt
   -- built.sbt
```

Now I want to package myfiles/myfile1.txt and myfiles/myfile2.txt into the output jar.

I tried to include this to the build.sbt file:

```
mappings in (Compile, packageBin) += {
  baseDirectory.value / "myfiles" / "myfile1.txt" -> "File/myfile1.txt"
}

mappings in (Compile, packageBin) += {
  baseDirectory.value / "myfiles" / "myfile2.txt" -> "File/myfile2.txt"
}
```

but when I am using sbt assembly command, they are not included in the jar.

Where is wrong?